# MySQL: Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1111

I am using MySQL. Here is my schema:

Suppliers(**sid: integer**, sname: string, address string)

Parts(**pid: integer**, pname: string, color: string)

Catalog(**sid: integer, pid: integer**, cost: real)

(primary keys are bolded)

I am trying to write a query to select all parts that are made by at least two suppliers:

```
-- Find the pids of parts supplied by at least two different suppliers.
SELECT c1.pid                      -- select the pid
FROM Catalog AS c1                 -- from the Catalog table
WHERE c1.pid IN (                  -- where that pid is in the set:
    SELECT c2.pid                  -- of pids
    FROM Catalog AS c2             -- from catalog
    WHERE c2.pid = c1.pid AND COUNT(c2.sid) >= 2 -- where there are at least two corresponding sids
);
```

First off, am I even going about this the right way?

Secondly, I get this error:

> 1111 - Invalid use of group function

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 216, accepted):

You need to use `HAVING`, not `WHERE`.

The difference is: the `WHERE` clause filters which rows MySQL selects. *Then* MySQL groups the rows together and aggregates the numbers for your `COUNT` function.

`HAVING` is like `WHERE`, only it happens *after* the `COUNT` value has been computed, so it'll work as you expect. Rewrite your subquery as:

```
(                  -- where that pid is in the set:
SELECT c2.pid                  -- of pids
FROM Catalog AS c2             -- from catalog
WHERE c2.pid = c1.pid
HAVING COUNT(c2.sid) >= 2)
```

Comment: Also if GROUP BY is used, HAVING should be after GROUP BY

Comment: Also, GROUP BY needs to be before HAVING.... Should have read Bandolero's comment :D

Answer (score 13):

First, the error you're getting is due to where you're using the `COUNT` function -- you can't use an aggregate (or group) function in the `WHERE` clause.

Second, instead of using a subquery, simply join the table to itself:

```
SELECT a.pid 
FROM Catalog as a LEFT JOIN Catalog as b USING( pid )
WHERE a.sid != b.sid
GROUP BY a.pid
```

Which I believe should return only rows where at least two rows exist with the same `pid` but there is are at least 2 `sid`s.  To make sure you get back only one row per `pid` I've applied a grouping clause.

Comment: Is it possible I don't even need a join? (see my updated answer, where I supplied a possible solution.)

Comment: @Rosarch, I think you'll want to use `COUNT(DISTINCT sid)` in your updated query.

Comment: Wouldn't `sid` always have to be distinct anyway, because `sid` and `pid` together form a primary key for `Catalog`?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have an aggregate function in your where clause, another possible source of the `1111 - Invalid use of group function` error is if you have nested aggregate functions:

```
select sum(avg(close)) from prices;
(1111, 'Invalid use of group function')
```

You can get around this by breaking up the problem into two steps:

1. Save the inner aggregation into a variable

```
select @avg:=avg(close) from prices;
```

2. Run the outer aggregation against the variable

```
select sum(@avg) from prices;
```