# Why would this SQL error with "Invalid use of group function"?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, pdo, mysql-error-1111

This is a simple query ran when the user presses *logout* from my website

```
UPDATE `user_logins` 
   SET `active` = 0 
 WHERE `user_id` = 3 
   AND `datetime` = MAX(`datetime`) LIMIT 1
```

The `user_id` value is binded in there with PDO.

I get the following exception thrown

> Invalid use of group function

[Googling around](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8gfns=1&q=Invalid+use+of+group+function) seems to say that it is because I am using an aggregate function in a `WHERE` clause.

I also found this [question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330840/mysql-invalid-use-of-group-function), but playing around with `HAVING` didn't seem to work for me. I tried replacing the `AND` with `HAVING`.

How can I change this query to not use the aggregate (or to use `HAVING`), but still perform the same functionality?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
UPDATE `user_logins` SET `active` = 0
WHERE `user_id` = 3
ORDER BY `datetime` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

That will put the highest date time for that user first, and the `LIMIT 1` will ensure that only the first record gets updated if more than one record matches the query.

Comment: Thanks mate, also, clicking through to your site made me realise I read and enjoyed your [WordPress](http://www.phpvs.net/2009/12/08/an-exercise-in-wordpress-integration-or-why-wordpress-sucks/) article a few moons ago, thanks for that!

Comment: No prob, glad it helped.  Yeah, I was pretty frustrated with WP when I wrote that.  Hah... good times.