# Invalid use of group function SUM() in WHERE

Tags: mysql, subquery, sum, where-clause

I am having a problem with my query.

I want to use SUM in my WHERE but it keeps giving me Invalid use of group function.

```
AND SUM((invoices_out.net+invoices_out.vat)/currencies.rateVsPound)
>
(SELECT SUM(jobs_payments_accounts.amount/currencies.rateVsPound)
 FROM jobs_payments_accounts, jobs, enquiries, currencies
 WHERE jobs_payments_accounts.jobRef = jobs.id
 AND jobs_payments_accounts.currencyRef = currencies.id
 AND enquiries.id = jobs.enquiryRef
 AND enquiries.entityRef = ed.id)
```

The right side of > works perfectly, but how can I achieve what I'm trying to do with the left side?

Here is the full subquery:

```
IF(ed.paymentTermsRef = 3,
(SELECT SUM((invoices_out.net+invoices_out.vat)/currencies.rateVsPound)
FROM enquiries, jobs, (SELECT * FROM invoices_out_reference GROUP BY invoiceRef) AS iorUnique,
                                (SELECT enquiryRef, sellingCurrency FROM parts_trading GROUP BY enquiryRef) AS PTU,
                                currencies,
                                invoices_out
                                    WHERE enquiries.entityRef = ed.id
                                    AND enquiries.id = jobs.enquiryRef
                                    AND PTU.enquiryRef = enquiries.id
                                    AND PTU.sellingCurrency = currencies.id
                                    AND jobs.id = iorUnique.jobRef
                                    AND iorUnique.invoiceRef = invoices_out.id
                                    AND invoices_out.paid = 0
                                AND SUM((invoices_out.net+invoices_out.vat)/currencies.rateVsPound)
                                    >
                                    (SELECT SUM(jobs_payments_accounts.amount/currencies.rateVsPound)
                                         FROM jobs_payments_accounts, jobs, enquiries, currencies
                                         WHERE jobs_payments_accounts.jobRef = jobs.id
                                         AND jobs_payments_accounts.currencyRef = currencies.id
                                         AND enquiries.id = jobs.enquiryRef
                                         AND enquiries.entityRef = ed.id)
                                #AND jobs.id NOT IN
                                #       (SELECT jobRef FROM jobs_payments_accounts)
                                #   AND jobs.id NOT IN
                                #       (SELECT jobRef FROM jobs_payments_advance)
                                AND jobs.id IN
                                    (SELECT jobRef FROM invoices_out_reference)
                                AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), invoices_out.date) >= 30),
                                NULL
                             )
```

---

Tried implementing what you suggested with IS NULL but it makes the query **much** slower.

Still having a lot of trouble with this, hopefully I will crack it soon somehow.

Comment: In your select if you did "SELECT SUM(jobs_payments_accounts.amount/currencies.rateVsPound) as myval" can you not do where myval > ... (untested)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first rule of the "Aggregate functions users club" is:

> You don't use aggregate functions in WHERE

The second rule of the "Aggregate functions users club" is:

> You don't use aggregate functions in WHERE

`HAVING` clause has to be used in such cases: here's [a great topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330840/mysql-invalid-use-of-group-function) to study some intricacies of it.

And I really suggest restructuring your query (why use nested subqueries to check `jobs.id` in three different tables instead of `LEFT JOIN ... ON id IS NULL`, for example?) or dividing it into smaller ones with temporary tables. No offence, but when looking at what you've quoted, I actually can hear your DB cries.

Answer (score 8):

You must use `HAVING` with aggregate functions:

```
select ...
from ...
where ...
group by ...
having sum(...) > ...
```