# Get error #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, group-by, mysql-error-1111

I have a problem with this Query

```
SELECT SUM(ROUND( SUM( note=3 ) / count( note=3 ) )) AS AVG, sma_famille.famille
                FROM sma_notes, sma_famille, sma_agents, sma_service_activite
                WHERE sma_famille.id_famille >=14
                AND sma_famille.id_service =9
                AND sma_notes.id_agent >=7
                GROUP BY sma_famille.id_famille
```

and i get the error message

```
#1111 - Invalid use of group function
```

If somebody has experience with this kind of Query.

Here some details of the query:

I i take the query without the first SUM like this (This is the whole query Code)

```
    SELECT ROUND( SUM( note =3 ) / count( note =3 ) ) AS AVG, sma_famille.famille, sma_notes.id_agent
    FROM sma_notes, sma_famille, sma_agents, sma_service_activite
    WHERE sma_famille.id_famille >=14
    AND sma_famille.id_service =9
    AND sma_notes.id_agent >=7
    AND sma_notes.id_agent = sma_agents.id_agent
    AND sma_service_activite.id_activite = sma_notes.id_activite
    AND sma_service_activite.id_famille = sma_famille.id_famille
    GROUP BY sma_famille.id_famille, sma_notes.id_agent
```

Than i get results like:

```
    AVG | famille   | id_agent  
    3   |BEL        | 7 
    2   |BEL        | 8 
    1   |BEL        | 9 
    1   |CEL        | 7 
    2   |CEL        | 8 
    1   |CEL        | 9
```

But with my query who didn't works:

```
SELECT SUM(ROUND( SUM( note=3 ) / count( note=3 ) )) AS AVG, sma_famille.famille
    FROM sma_notes, sma_famille, sma_agents, sma_service_activite
        WHERE sma_famille.id_famille >=14
        AND sma_famille.id_service =9
        AND sma_notes.id_agent >=7
        AND sma_notes.id_agent = sma_agents.id_agent
        AND sma_service_activite.id_activite = sma_notes.id_activite
        AND sma_service_activite.id_famille = sma_famille.id_famille
        GROUP BY sma_famille.id_famille
```

i want to get this result:

```
    AVG | famille
    6   |BEL    
    4   |CEL
```

Thanks in advance

Achillix

Cheers

Comment: read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330840/mysql-invalid-use-of-group-function

Answer (score 2):

You should have used `HAVING` clause instead of `WHERE`.

See below.

Consider I have table `Address` with columns as `City` & `State`.

**`HAVING` is used to check conditions after the aggregation takes place.**

**`WHERE` is used before the aggregation takes place.**

This code:

```
select City, CNT=Count(1)
From Address
Where State = 'MA'
Group By City
```

Gives you a count of all the cities in MA.

This code:

```
select City, CNT=Count(1)
From Address
Where State = 'MA'
Group By City
Having Count(1)>5
```

Gives you the count of all the cities in MA that occur 6 or more times.

Also read

[`Definition, Comparison and Difference between HAVING and WHERE Clause`](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/04/sql-server-definition-comparison-and-difference-between-having-and-where-clause/)

[`Where Vs Having`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25258/Where-Vs-Having-Difference-between-having-and-Wher).

Comment: I have put at the end of my query     HAVING COUNT(AVG) >1     but still i get the same error message. It is frustrated :-(
Or if i have otherwhere inside of the query an error???

Comment: @achillix : instead of `WHERE` use `HAVING`

Comment: No it doesn't works. I had replace Where with HAVING but i get an error message #1064 Syntax Error near near 'GROUP BY sma_famille.famille HAVING SUM(AVG) >1
Can't understand