# SQL Error (1111): Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch data between the (max date in the entrydate column) and (max date in the entrydate column-15days)!!

Table1:Totally it has 953rows
[image]

Table2: Totally it has 400rows
[image]

i got this error ,Please help me !!

```
    Select  
o_material_transaction_inward.Mat_Code,
s_material_details.Mat_Spec,
s_material_details.Mat_Make,
o_material_transaction_inward.Sup_Name,
o_material_transaction_inward.Entry_Date,
o_material_transaction_inward.DC_qty,
o_material_transaction_inward.Received_qty,
    from 
o_material_transaction_inward 
    join 
s_material_details 
    on 
s_material_details.Mat_Code=o_material_transaction_inward.Mat_Code and s_material_details.Mat_Group_Id=o_material_transaction_inward.Mat_Group_id
    where 
o_material_transaction_inward.Entry_Date between Max(o_material_transaction_inward.Entry_Date) and Max(o_material_transaction_inward.Entry_Date - 15)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Fixed `BETWEEN` predicate:

The reason it wasn't working is that the lowest value need to be the first value in the `BETWEEN` predicate, so in order to get those rows from the two tables having the `entry_date` between the max entry date - 15 and max entry date try this:

```
SELECT
  o.Mat_Code,
  s.Mat_Spec,
  s.Mat_Make,
  o.Sup_Name,
  DATE_FORMAT(o.Entry_Date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS Entry_Date,
  o.DC_qty,
  o.Received_qty
FROM o_material_transaction_inward AS o
INNER JOIN s_material_details      AS s  ON s.Mat_Code     = o.Mat_Code
WHERE o.Entry_Date BETWEEN ((SELECT Max(Entry_Date) 
                            FROM o_material_transaction_inward) - 15)
                       AND (SELECT Max(Entry_Date) 
                            FROM o_material_transaction_inward) ;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9615/10)

Comment: 0rows affected as the output , i used Having instead of between but it fetched all the rows except  the 15rows i expected.

Comment: @RanjitKumar - Can you please add some sample data of these two tables `o_material_transaction_inward`, `s_material_details` and the expected result that you want to get from these two tables. This will be very helpful. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    Select  
o_material_transaction_inward.Mat_Code,
s_material_details.Mat_Spec,
s_material_details.Mat_Make,
o_material_transaction_inward.Sup_Name,
o_material_transaction_inward.Entry_Date,
o_material_transaction_inward.DC_qty,
o_material_transaction_inward.Received_qty,
    from 
o_material_transaction_inward 
    join 
s_material_details 
    on 
s_material_details.Mat_Code=o_material_transaction_inward.Mat_Code and s_material_details.Mat_Group_Id=o_material_transaction_inward.Mat_Group_id
    having 
o_material_transaction_inward.Entry_Date between Max(o_material_transaction_inward.Entry_Date) and Max(o_material_transaction_inward.Entry_Date - 15)
```

(see the accepted answer of [MySQL: Invalid use of group function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330840/mysql-invalid-use-of-group-function) for an explanation of `where` vs `having`)

Comment: it Fetched all the rows expect the 15 rows !!

Comment: SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'o_material_transaction_inward.Entry_Date' in 'having clause'

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT
  o.Mat_Code,
  s.Mat_Spec,
  s.Mat_Make,
  o.Sup_Name,
  o.Entry_Date,
  o.DC_qty,
  o.Received_qty,
FROM o_material_transaction_inward AS o
INNER JOIN s_material_details      AS s  ON s.Mat_Code     = o.Mat_Code
                                        AND s.Mat_Group_Id = o.Mat_Group_id
WHERE o.Entry_Date BETWEEN (SELECT Max(Entry_Date) 
                            FROM o_material_transaction_inward) 
                       AND (SELECT Max(Entry_Date) 
                            FROM o_material_transaction_inward) - 15);
```

Comment: No error and also 0 rows affected as output .It havent fetched the Data between the (Max date) and (Max date-15)

Comment: For selecting the Max(Entry Date) i used this below query but it haven't worked. (SELECT DATE_SUB(Max(Entry_Date),INTERVAL 15 DAY) FROM o_material_transaction_inward) in the last line