# need to update the DB table through macros

Tags: mysql, vba

I need to do the below update through macros,

```
If tbname = "PARTY" Then
Dim ssql As String
ssql = "Update PARTY Set PARTY_ID= (SELECT (max(PARTY_ID)+1) FROM PARTY) WHERE PARTY_ID ='DUMMY'
DB.Execute ssql, 64
End If
```

I am getting this error, while running the above statement.

> Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'PARTY' for update in
>   FROM clause   0.000 sec

Is there any other way to update the `max(party_id)+1` to the row having party_id as "DUMMY"

Comment: you forgot a closing quote in your ssql declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're having is in your SQL.  You shouldn't be using a subselect here. The from-clause you're having is complete bull, because `Update PARTY` implies `From PARTY`

Additionally you seem to be calculating something strange, since you get an "invalid use of group function"-error. Short googling reveals [this stackoverflow question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330840) suggesting you should be using HAVING instead of WHERE

The fix is thusly simple:

```
ssql = "Update PARTY set PARTY_IT=(max(PARTY_ID) + 1) HAVING PARTY_ID='DUMMY'"
```

Comment: Update PARTY Set PARTY_ID = (MAX(PARTY_ID*1)+1) WHERE PARTY_ID = '10083'
its throwing error as " invalid use of group function"

Comment: i tried this and its working :)

ssql = " Update PARTY Set PARTY_ID = (SELECT MAX(PARTY_ID*1)+1 FROM (SELECT * FROM PARTY) AS PARTY_ID ) WHERE PARTY_ID = 'DUMMY' "