# Symfony / Doctrine COUNT Group By and Left JOIN

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two Tables in symfony join by ManyToOne bidirectional relationship. articles and dates.

I would like to sum all the d.quantity for the same a.id How can I do that ?

I try :

In my table (dates) i have :

```
+----------------------------
| id   | a.id  |   quantity
+----------------------------
| 1    | 4     |      1 
| 2    | 4     |      3
| 3    | 6     |      4
| 4    | 5     |      6
| 5    | 4     |      15 
----------------------------

$allIndispo = $qb
    ->select('a2.id')
    ->leftJoin('a2.dates', 'd')
    ->where('(a2.quantity - COUNT(d.quantity)) <= 0')
    ->groupBy('d.quantity')
    ->orderBy('a2.id', 'ASC');
```

Comment: Don't you want to group by a.id and SUM quantity then?

Comment: Yes but when i change group by a2.id i get : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1111 Invalid use dof GROUP

Comment: That may be to do with your WHERE clause than the GROUP BY clause. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330840/mysql-invalid-use-of-group-function might be of relevance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to use [HAVING](http://doctrine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#group-by-having-clauses) instead of WHERE, and group by the a.id, not for quantity, and project (in the select) the result.

```
$allIndispo = $qb
    ->select('a2.id, SUM(a2.quantity) as total')
    ->leftJoin('a2.dates', 'd')
    ->groupBy('a2.id')
    ->having('(a2.quantity - COUNT(d.quantity)) <= 0')
    ->orderBy('a2.id', 'ASC');
```

Answer (score -2):

You should read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)

```
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Product');

// createQueryBuilder automatically selects FROM AppBundle:Product
// and aliases it to "p"
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->where('p.price > :price')
    ->setParameter('price', '19.99')
    ->orderBy('p.price', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery();

$products = $query->getResult();
// to get just one result:
// $product = $query->setMaxResults(1)->getOneOrNullResult();
```