# Doctrine get Product with most sales

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a Product Entity with many Orders as association.
I want to build a repository method that brings the most sold products.
Each order only have 1 product with 1 quantity so, quantity is irrelevant.

My current progress in ProductRepository:

```
    public function getMostPopularProducts($limit)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder("p")
            ->join(Order::class, "o", "o.item = p.id")
            ->setMaxResults($limit)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```

What would be the best approach here to Join the orders, count total amount of orders and retrieve a result ordered from most sold product to less sold product.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symfony / Doctrine COUNT Group By and Left JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37485778/symfony-doctrine-count-group-by-and-left-join)

Comment: @yivi no it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rookie me was obviously doing this wrong.
Right approach is to go from Orders into Products and not the other way around.

This works.

```
    public function getMostSoldItems()
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder("o")
            ->groupBy("o.item")
            ->setMaxResults(10)
            ->orderBy("COUNT(o.item)", "ASC")
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```