# MYSQL Sakila Database - Find a list of customers who have not rented a movie yet

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm learning SQL for the first time in a university course, and we're using the popular Sakila Database. I'm stuck with the question - Find a list of customers who have not rented a movie yet. So far my thought process is something like this:

```
#List of customers who have not rented a movie yet
SELECT
    concat(c.first_name, " ", c.last_name), count(r.rental_id) as "Number of Rentals"
FROM
    customer c, rental r
WHERE
    c.customer_id = r.customer_id
    AND count(r.rental_id) is NULL
GROUP BY
    c.customer_id;
```

However, I keep getting the error "Invalid Use of Group Function" and I can't seem to figure out why. Can someone please help me?

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: SQL Error 1111: Invalid use of group function.

Comment: You don't need any counting or grouping. You just need to think about the different types of joins. Does that help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Invalid use of group function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330840/mysql-invalid-use-of-group-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the `WHERE` statement to `Having` statement, like this:

```
SELECT
    concat(c.first_name, " ", c.last_name), count(r.rental_id) as "Number of Rentals"
FROM
    customer c, rental r
WHERE 
    c.customer_id = r.customer_id
GROUP BY
    c.customer_id
HAVING count(r.rental_id) is NULL
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped!